# Simple terminal graphics line drawing

Tags: graphics, forth

The program starts at the center of the screen and starts drawing a line in 50ms steps. When the line hits the edge of the terminal it will be reflected and continue drawing. `steps` takes the number of drawing steps to perform before finishing while `until-key` finishes on a key press.

Apart from the lack of comments, what would I need to do to make this "good" Forth and how would I change it to fit in one screen (16 lines of 64 chars)?

```
variable h
variable w
: height h @ ;
: width  w @ ;

variable point-var
cell allot
: point ( offset -- addr ) cells point-var + ;

variable direction-var
cell allot
: dir ( offset -- addr ) cells direction-var + ;

: init ( -- )
    rows h !
    cols w !
    width  2 / 0 point !
    height 2 / 1 point !
    1 0 dir !
    1 1 dir ! ;


: reflect-top ( -- t/f )
    1 point @ 0= dup if 1 1 dir ! then invert ;
: reflect-bot ( -- t/f )
    1 point @ height 1 - = if -1 1 dir ! then ;
: reflect-left ( -- t/f )
    0 point @ width 1 - = if -1 0 dir ! then ;
: reflect-right ( -- t/f )
    0 point @ 0= dup if 1 0 dir ! then invert ;
: reflect ( -- )
    reflect-top if reflect-bot then
    reflect-right if reflect-left then ;

: draw-point ( -- ) [char] # emit ;

: move-x ( -- n ) 0 point @ 0 dir @ + dup 0 point ! ;
: move-y ( -- n ) 1 point @ 1 dir @ + dup 1 point ! ;
: move-xy ( -- ) move-x move-y at-xy ;

: try ;

: step ( -- )
    try reflect
    move-xy draw-point ;

: steps ( n -- )
    init
    page
    0 do step 50 ms loop ;

: until-key ( n -- )
    init
    page
    begin step 50 ms key? until ;
```

Comment: Good material for the review. However some parts seem missing (`at-xy`, `invert`).

Comment: `invert` (used as logical not) and `at-xy` are provided by gforth in the base dictionary. `at-xy ( posX posY -- )` just prints the "\x1b[y;xH" escape sequence to move the cursor.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 5 → 4. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. You may wish to post it as a self-answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Magic numbers**

  ```
      0 constant X
      1 constant Y
  ```

  looks more attractive than naked 0 and 1. I suppose (sorry can't test it right now) it may let you unify `move-x` with `move-y`, as well as reflects.
- **Height and width**

  ```
      : height= h @ 1 - = ;
      : width=  w @ 1 - = ;
  ```

  allow more symmetric definition of reflects:

  ```
      : reflect-top Y point @ 0=      dup  if  1 1 dir ! then invert ;
      : reflect-bot Y point @ height=      if -1 1 dir ! then ;
  ```

  Now it looks like they have different stack effects, which is strange. Are you sure `reflect-bot` doesn't miss `dup`?
- **`move-*`**

  I'd rearrange pushes, e.g.

  ```
      : move-x 0 0 0 point @ dir @ + dup point ! ;
      : move-y 1 1 1 point @ dir @ + dup point ! ;
  ```

  which really prompts for a `point @ dir @ + dup point !` word. `move-in-dir` perhaps?
- **One screen**

  Do modern Forthers still care about screens?

Comment: Ah `reflect-bot` should have `( -- )` as the diagram. I missed that when fixing a problem I had with it earlier. Also I wanted to see how it would look if it was done in one screen (currently trying) to help avoid variables as they are a lot slower than pure stack operations.

Comment: @SANK Yes variables are generally frowned upon. I am still trying to see a way to avoid them here.

Comment: wouldn't the pushes in move-* will cause undefined behaviour (segfault) if rearranged as `dir` would be using the value from `point @` instead of x/y?

Comment: @SANK I don't think so. My suggestion is a literal rewrite (as far as I understand); it shown;t change the behaviour.

Comment: Since both `point` and `dir` consume a stack item, `0 0 point @` will leave the stack with `[point value, 0]` which `dir` then consumes causing a segfault when `point @` returns greater than 1. `0 0 0 point @ swap dir @ + dup rot point !` works as each must consume a `0` from the stack (currently testing it in gforth).

Answer (score 1):

Almost complete solution to the screen improvement with the bulk taking 15 lines.

- All variables have been removed along with most of the words to define reflect.
- The position, direction and bounds are now stored in 6 cells allocated on the heap.
- "Half" words only used to define others are now replaced by the words they are used to define.

There should also be a slight speedup due to avoiding variables and lower word count per definition.

```
: bound ( a -- a ) 4 cells + ;
: dir ( a -- a ) 2 cells + ;
: init ( n n a -- a ) rot tuck ! cell + tuck ! cell + ;
: init ( -- a )
    6 cells allocate throw dup
    rows 2 / cols 2 / init 1 1 init rows 1-  cols 1- init drop ;
: reflect ( a -- )
    dup @ 0= if 1 swap dir ! else dup dup bound @ swap @ =
    if -1 swap dir ! else drop then then ;
: reflect ( a -- ) dup cell + reflect reflect ;
: move-xy ( a -- )
    dup @ over dir @ + over ! cell + dup @ over dir @ + swap ! ;
: step ( a -- )
    dup dup dup reflect cell + @ swap @ swap at-xy
    move-xy [char] # emit ;

: steps ( n -- )
    page init swap 0 do dup step 10 ms loop
    dup 6 erase free throw ;

: until-key ( -- )
    page init begin dup step key? 10 ms until
    dup 6 erase free throw ;
```